# Nginx can't connect to uWSGI socket with correct permissions

Tags: nginx, sockets

I'm trying to connect Nginx to uWSGI so I can run an application written in Ruby (where I am not able to use passenger). This is my virtual host configuration:

```
server {    
        listen unix:/var/run/nginx/redmine.sock;
        root /var/www/redmine/public;

        location / {
                try_files $uri @uwsgi;
        }

        location @uwsgi {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/uwsgi/redmine.sock;
        }
}
```

It's easy, I try to find a static file, otherwise I pass to uwsgi listening on unix socket. This regards me a 502 error of "bad gateway". I went to read the error logs and I have the following:

```
2014/09/09 20:08:56 [crit] 20922#0: *29484 connect() to unix:/var/run/uwsgi/redmine.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: unix:, server: , request: "GET /redmine HTTP/1.0", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/run/uwsgi/redmine.sock:", host: "localhost"
```

But I was pretty sure I have configured uWSGI to use the same user Nginx does:

```
user nginx;
```

and

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/redmine.sock
chdir = /var/www/redmine
rails = .
plugins = 0:rack_ruby20
rack = config.ru
idle = 3600

chmod-socket = 660
chown-socket = nginx:nginx
uid = nginx
gid = nginx
```

And the socket is:

```
fenix ~ # ls -lh /var/run/uwsgi/redmine.sock 
srw-rw---- 1 nginx nginx 0 Set  9 20:08 /var/run/uwsgi/redmine.sock
```

So Nginx can't even read and write to a socket it owns? What is this supposed to mean? I can't figure out how to do it.

I noticed also that Nginx won't work even if the socket permissions are 777.

Comment: Why your nginx listens to the same socket as uwsgi? Probably it should be `listen 80;`

Comment: @AlexeyTen no, it does not. The paths are different.

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed it.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue with permissions and it was a result of SELinux not having the policy for nginx to write to sockets

You can check SELinux AVC messages via `audit2why -al` to see more details of the error, something along the lines of

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1414460265.454:2612): avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=22107 comm="nginx" path="/tmp/uwsgi.sock" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=unix_stream_socket
Was caused by:
    Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

    You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

To add the enforcement policy for nginx, first confirm the enforcement policy by running

```
> grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m nginx
```

You should see an output similar to

```
module nginx 1.0;

require {
    type unconfined_t;
    type httpd_t;
    type home_root_t;
    type soundd_port_t;
    class sock_file write;
    class unix_stream_socket connectto;
    class tcp_socket name_connect;
}

#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t home_root_t:sock_file write;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t soundd_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
allow httpd_t unconfined_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```

Finally you load the custom policy by running

```
> grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nginx
> semodule -i nginx.pp
```

Comment: I do not have SELinux

Comment: You can check if SELinux is enabled by running `sestatus` .

Comment: On CentOS6.6 I needed to install audit2allow. I did this: `yum install setroubleshoot`